# How to send data from android wear to phone using Message API?

Tags: java, android

I am using the tutorial from [this site](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/a-guide-to-the-android-wear-message-api/152).

I was able to send data from wear to phone, so I tried sending data from wear to phone using the save system (but I did not write the service to check to message in background). I open both the app in my wear emulator and one plus one phone.
I was sucessful.

Then I tried the other way around like this:

My code:

My manifest file(watch)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="diwakar.com.messagingapi2phone">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java (for watch)

```
package diwakar.com.messagingapi2phone;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Node;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.NodeApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements  GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{

    private TextView currentSentTextView;

    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

    private Button mButton1;
    private Button mButton2;
    private Button mButton3;
    private Button mButton4;

    private static final String DATA1 = "1";
    private static final String DATA2 = "2";
    private static final String DATA3 = "3";
    private static final String DATA4 = "4";

    private static final String START_ACTIVITY = "/start_activity";
    private static final String WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH = "/message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send1);
        mButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send2);
        mButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send3);
        mButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send4);

        currentSentTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_currentSent);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        initGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    public void send1(View view) {
        currentSentTextView.setText(DATA1);
        sendMessage(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, DATA1);
    }

    public void send2(View view) {
        currentSentTextView.setText(DATA2);
        sendMessage(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, DATA2);


    }

    public void send3(View view) {
        currentSentTextView.setText(DATA3);
        sendMessage(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, DATA3);


    }

    public void send4(View view) {
        currentSentTextView.setText(DATA4);
        sendMessage(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH, DATA4);

    }

    //initializing the API Client
    private void initGoogleApiClient(){

        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();

        mApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        sendMessage(START_ACTIVITY, "");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    private void sendMessage(final String path, final String text){

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes( mApiClient ).await();
                for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                    MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                            mApiClient, node.getId(), path, text.getBytes() ).await();
                }

                runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        currentSentTextView.setText( text );
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (for wear)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button_send1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="send1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button_send2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_send1"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="send2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button_send3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_send1"
        android:onClick="send3"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/button_send4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_send3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_send2"
        android:onClick="send4"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Not Sent Yet!"
        android:id="@+id/textView_currentSent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java (for phone)

```
package diwakar.com.messagingapi2phone;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.MessageEvent;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MessageApi.MessageListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private static final String WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH = "/message";

    private GoogleApiClient mApiClient;

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        initGoogleApiClient();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(final MessageEvent messageEvent) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("TAG", "arrived");

                if (messageEvent.getPath().equalsIgnoreCase(WEAR_MESSAGE_PATH)) {
                    textView.setText(new String(messageEvent.getData()));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (mApiClient != null)
            mApiClient.unregisterConnectionCallbacks(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void initGoogleApiClient(){

        mApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .build();

        mApiClient.connect();

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml(for wear)

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

my manifest file(phone)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="diwakar.com.messagingapi2phone" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Now I opened my app both on my phone and the wear emulator but this time around this did not work and I couldn't figure out why?